# zipper effect using php/jQuery like "zipper google doodle"

Tags: html, jquery, css

Would it be possible to make a zipper effect on the page using jquery rather than flash? For example the following but without flash (and sitting vertically):
https://web.archive.org/web/20120621081324/http://activeden.net/item/interactive-zipper/92456

The best I can do is get my zip to go down and then the 2 sides open sliding horizontally

my attempt,

```
$("#openbox").click(function() {
    
    $("#openbox").stop().delay(0).animate({
        "top": "+=600px"
    }, 600);
    $curtainopen = false;
    
    $(".leftcurtain").stop().delay(600).animate({
        "left": "-=380px"
    }, 3000);
    
    $(".rightcurtain").stop().delay(600).animate({
        "right": "-=390px"
    }, 3000);
    
    $curtainopen = true;

    return false;
});
```

CSS

```
#openbox {
    width:38px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(images/zip.png);
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:420px;
    z-index:6
}
.leftcurtain {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    background-position:right;
    z-index: 5;
    background-image:url(images/frontcurtain-left.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.rightcurtain {
    width: 52%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    background-image:url(images/frontcurtain-right.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.rightcurtain img, .leftcurtain img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes... I generally say anything is possible in jQuery that can be done in flash.  But you may have issues on older browsers.  Here's one possible method to attempt this.

You'd need 3 images.

1. zipper handle and mouth
2. image of the upper zip line
3. image of the lower zip line

Basically, you'd have a black div on top of the 2 zip images, with the handle/mouth positioned in the middle.  You need to alter the width of the black div as the zipper is moved left, and alter the positions of the two zipper images to the left in relation to that movement.  Set your overflow to the containers of the images, and blamo.... you have yourself a jquery zipper, which the content underneath would be uncovered as you zip.

Comment: i understand your method but starting to think it might be out of my scope lol, but i will take another look at it using your approach